# XSLT group parent

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT. I need to get the following result from xml/xsl transform

```
<root>
<abc>
    <aaa></aaa>
    <aaa></aaa>
    <aaa></aaa>
    <bbb>
        <ccc></ccc>
    </bbb>
 </abc>
</root>
```

i would like the output html to be something like:

```
<root>
<abc>
  <ddd>
    <aaa></aaa>
    <aaa></aaa>
    <aaa></aaa>
  </ddd>
  <bbb>
     <ccc></ccc>
  </bbb>
 </abc>
 </root>
```

please help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you tried, and what problems you encountered.

Comment: Please also say (a) which version of XSLT, (b) what exactly is the logic here - do you simply want to gather _all_ `aaa` elements together into a single `ddd` or do you want to wrap groups of _adjacent_ `aaa` elements separately?

Comment: Version 2.0 and I want to gather all <aaa> elements into a single <ddd>. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If, indeed, you are just gathering `aaa` elements into a single `ddd` then this is straight-forward in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

First, read up about the XSLT [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which on its on copies nodes as-is to the output.

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then, you only need a template for the nodes you are transform. In this case, you are transform the `abc` element by adding a new child.

To gather together all the `aaa` elements into a single `ddd`, you just do this

```
     <ddd>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="aaa" />
     </ddd>
```

Then to process the other children, just do this to select everything other than `aaa`

```
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::aaa)]" />
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="abc">
     <ddd>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="aaa" />
     </ddd>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::aaa)]" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```